# How to keep a mushroom placed even when it is exposed to high light level?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In Minecraft, there is a problem with creating a map containing Mushrooms. When placing the Mushrooms, they don't stay on the ground as a block, instead they turn back into items because of high light level. **The problem is that I don't wish to have a lower light level** - this makes the map looking badly.
    **Does someone know how to preserve the Mushrooms as a block in a highly lit place?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you place the mushroom on **Mycelium**, the light rules do not apply. [From the docs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mycelium):

> Mushrooms can remain on mycelium blocks **in any light level**, unlike the situation on other blocks, where mushrooms are broken (dropping as items) during block updates in high light.

If you are making a downloadable map, and you don't like the look of Mycelium, you could create a resource pack with that texture replaced with one you want, and recommend it to be downloaded and used with the map.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the map low light and effect everyone with night vision.

You can also try surrounding the mushroom with barriers so no light can get in it.

Comment: Rookie, barriers are transparent to light

Comment: I also thought about the night vision solution, but that would mean that there will be no sunlight. I need the sunlight for daylight sensors, because otherwise the redstone circuit will not work.

Comment: My bad. Sorry about the barriers

Comment: use the setblock command. /setblock ~ ~ ~ red_mushroom    i haven't tested it tho